# Sqlite UPDATE question

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

Hi i'm writing an iphone application that requires sqlite and one update query. So simply,why this works:

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",
    @"UPDATE ZTABELLA SET ZTYPE =",@"1",
    @" WHERE ZNAME='",@"stringaoggetto",@"';"];

sqlite3_exec(database2, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

and why this doesn't works:

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",
    @"UPDATE ZTABELLA SET ZTYPE =",@"1",
    @" WHERE ZNAME='",oggetto,@"';"];

sqlite3_exec(database2, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The difference between this two examples is only `@"stringaoggetto"` in the first and `oggetto` in the second. In the first i have inserted value directly with a string,in the second example `oggetto` is a nsstring object that have the right value inside (i have printed a nslog). Why this difference?

The log for query is the same for each example:

```
NSLog(@" %@",query);
//this log print: UPDATE ZTABELLA SET ZTYPE =1 WHERE ZNAME='stringaoggetto';
```

The log for the nsstring object "oggetto" is:

```
NSLog(@"%@",oggetto);
//this log print   stringaoggetto
```

I have also tried another code to check the error,but the result is the same:

```
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath2 UTF8String], &database2) == SQLITE_OK) {


      const char *update = "UPDATE ZTABELLA SET ZTYPE =1 WHERE ZNAME=?";

      sqlite3_stmt *updatestmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database2, update, -1, &updatestmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

sqlite3_bind_text(updatestmt, 1, [oggetto UTF8String] , -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updatestmt)){

    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database2));

                }
sqlite3_reset(updatestmt);                  

            }
            else {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database2));

            }
            }
```

As the first direct query (with sqlite3_exc) in this case the sqlite3_bind_text doesn't works after where clause. With the same query if i try for testing purpose to set column ZTYPE insted of ZNAME (however any other column can't be set "Where") it works. Why?

This is the init of the nsstring oggetto,is the result of select query:

```
NSMutableString *oggetto;
oggetto=[NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
```

this string retain correctly the value (the value is "stringaoggetto"),i have tried with a nslog.

Comment: What value does oggetto have?  You should also bind values instead of including directly.

Comment: either because your oggetto is not having the same value as @"stringaoggetto" or because your tableNames are different in both the queries.

Comment: I'm sorry the different tableName is my a mistake,i've edited the question. I've posted the nsstring oggetto object log,you can see that it print stringaoggetto. However the query log print the same result in both examples.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do this instead; [query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] I think this is really the key you need to solve this issue. Ensure that the string is being retained; Both these should work.

   NSLog(@"%s",[query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

   NSLog(@"%s",[query UTF8String]);
2. This may have some helpful hints also; http://www.how2s.org/index.php/How_to_get_started_with_SQLite_on_the_iPhone
   Simplify the design.
3. Also of note, you use NULL,NULL, NULL.  Get the error data from the sqlite3_exec statement. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html has reference material to get you started on that.
4. you listed multiple issues. Separate the others out to other questions. Inserts are different from Updates. Focus this question on the Update.
5. If none of this helped, how did NSString *oggetto get set, where, same file, diff file, is it a function argument etc?

Comment: i have tried [query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; insted,but the result is the same. I have tried also in the second piece of code (insertstm it's only the name,it is an update query,i'm sorry i've already edited the question) without success. I have inserted the init of the nsstring,is the result of a select query (with select query there isn't any problem,they works perfectly)